# How are the emoji images encoded in AndroidEmoji-htc.ttf file?

Tags: android, image, reverse-engineering, truetype

What file type is being used to embed the images in [AndroidEmoji-htc.ttf](http://elegancia.mobi/websvn/filedetails.php?repname=elegancia-rom-m7-nightly&path=/system/fonts/AndroidEmoji-htc.ttf&rev=47&peg=47&language=sl)? direct download: [AndroidEmoji-htc.ttf](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/450507/AndroidEmoji-htc.ttf)

Images can be extracted from [AppleColorEmoji.ttf](https://github.com/potyt/fonts/blob/master/macfonts/Apple%20Color%20Emoji/Apple%20Color%20Emoji.ttf) easily because the [PNG headers](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Structure.html) can be found using a hex editor. This [ruby script](https://github.com/tmm1/emoji-extractor) can extract them. The algorithm is [described here](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/140784).

Sample of file in hex editor:

```
0706 2627 2626 2726 2627 2626 2727 2727  ..&'&&'&&'&&''''
2726 2627 2626 2726 2627 2636 3736 3637  '&&'&&'&&'&67667
3636 3736 3637 3737 3737 3636 3736 3637  6676677777667667
3636 0131 3636 3736 3635 3527 2626 3132  66.16676655'&&12
2627 2626 2726 2627 2721 2115 1533 3232  &'&&'&&''!!..322
1716 1617 1634 1110 0607 0606 0706 0623  .....4.........#
2315 1533 3335 3523 2226 2726 2627 3434  #..3355#"&'&&'44
3535 3332 3233 1616 1716 1617 1616 1716  553223..........
1617 1616 1716 1617 1616 1716 3237 3236  ............2726
3737 3736 3637 3636 3737 2323 0706 0607  7776676677##....
0606 0706 0627 2226 2726 2627 2626 2726  .....'"&'&&'&&'&
2627 2626 3130 2627 2626 2726 2627 2626  &'&&10&'&&'&&'&&
2727 3535 3736 3637 3636 0131 3232 3332  ''55766766.12232
1617 1616 1716 3017 1616 1516 0607 0606  ......0.........
0706 0607 0606 2323 3534 3437 3636 3736  ......##54476676
3608 bf05 020b 1c2a 0d09 0b0d 66a4 b72c  6......*....f..,
0202 0233 8a8d 9c9c 8d88 3302 0202 022a  ...3......3....*
9a8d 631a 3c05 090b 3e1a 1a3e 0b09 0b0d  ..c.<...>..>....
65a5 b918 1616 1d67 6572 4028 2a0f 251f  e......ger@(*.%.
7365 691b 1814 1a98 8d65 183b 0409 0d2c  sei......e.;...,
1a0b 0702 fb8b 1e1d 423e 3f44 2a0d 3a3f  ........B>?D*.:?
034f 4f42 4435 3203 1e1b 040d 140d 0704  .OOBD52.........
0303 040d 1b0d 041b 1e03 3235 4442 4f4f  ..........25DBOO
033f 3a0d 2a55 5265 1f21 3d40 4044 2a0d  .?:.*URe.!=@@D*.
3940 024d 4f44 4235 3502 1d1c 050d 1a0d  9@.MODB55.......
0502 0207 040d 140d 051c 1d02 3535 4244  ............55BD
4f4d 0240 390d 2a56 5301 c806 0d0b 2611  OM.@9.*VS.....&.
0b06 0503 120b 122e 1835 0837 33fe d9fe  .........5.73...
dc2e 2c02 0b12 0407 0b02 0306 071a 1006  ..,.............
2a23 f8fb 2a30 070f 1d0d 022a 1818 0914  *#..*0.....*....
```

**Update 6/18/2014:**
At @naXa 's suggestion, opening the file in [FontForge](http://fontforge.org) version 20120731-ML (current newest version) gave this error:

> The following table(s) in the font have been ignored by FontForge
>    Ignoring 'dcmj'
>   In GID1 the advance width (2252) is greater than the stated maximum (2048)
>    Subsequent errors will not be reported.
>   Bad lookup table: format=6, first=65535 total glyphs in font=894

[image: FontForge error after opening]

Somewhat expected because emojis in TTFs to this day are encoded proprietarily. The fact that I even see black and white emoji images using FontForge is a huge success because it means the TTF is standard for the most part. TTFs are not supposed to store color information I don't think.

They key is probably accessing the data in the dcmj table or wherever it is pointing to. Researching FontForge I found that BMP is a common image format for TTFs so I'm going to try and modify the [ruby script](https://github.com/tmm1/emoji-extractor) using those assumptions and report back!

**Update: 6/18/14**

I found what appear to be BMP headers [source1](http://www.fastgraph.com/help/bmp_header_format.html) [source2](http://imageformatsinfo.blogspot.com/2010/10/bmp-image-format.html), starting with `424D` using a hex editor but the header doesn't seem valid.

Next I would try:

1. Parsing the TTF look at the data in each "glyph" to see if I can find more patterns. I imagine the ttf will say the start end end of the image data.
2. Look into the htc android apk to see how they are pulling and displaying emoji from the ttf.

I've run out of time on this for now, if anyone has any other suggestions I'm very interested.

**UPDATE 6/20/2014**

Double clicking on the glyph using @naXa's suggestion and exporting as any of the formats will give me non color icons of any size but still does not reveal the color bitmap emojis I was looking for.

I went down to the store to look at an HTC phone finally and saw, to my surprise, they are using Apple's emoji font seen through the messaging app:

[image: Picture of Emoji in HTC messaging app]

I am almost certain these are stored in the HTC font provided above, but this conclusion has left extracting these images far less desirable.

Howver, it would still be cool to know, as a proof of concept, how to extract the color emojis. :)

EDIT: As Jasper pointed out, HTC does in fact have a custom emoji set as linked in his answer. The picture above was from a non updated phone. Still need to figure out how to extract these emojis!!

Comment: First of all you need to be aware of legal aspects: glyphs are copyrighted matter - you cannot simply choose any font and rip off its glyphs. Regarding your question: Have you tried [FontForge](http://fontforge.org/)? It can open ttf, export glyphs to svg, and then using any image converter you can get image in the desired format (for example, look at [this image to png converter](http://image.online-convert.com))

Comment: I've edited the question with findings regarding [FontForge](http://fontforge.org). Thank you

Comment: I couldn't extract the images using FontForge using @naXa. Any other helpful suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried to double click any glyph and export it as svg?

Comment: I can export the black and white emojis that way, but it still does not reveal the color ones. However, I'm not nearly as interested now in extracting them now, since I found they are a duplication of Apple, a bounty worthy conclusion @naXa helped me reach if there are no other answers ;).

Comment: As far as I know, TTF does not support coloured glyphs...

Comment: Quote from the [Android Central Forums](http://forums.androidcentral.com/general-help-how/241050-solved-android-4-1-ios-how-emoji-works-android-ios.html#post2497327): At this stage, there appears to be NO WAY to get the nice "picture" emoji like Apple because Apple apparently uses custom/proprietary extensions to the TTF file. You see these "picture" emoji in WhatsApp, etc. on Android because the app detects and replaces the unicode TTF characters with suitable images. It is apparently NOT in the TTF file itself, because TTF does not support colour or images at this stage.

Comment: Regarding the bounty: I don't want to take your last rep points  As soon as you'll cancel the bounty, I promise to move these comments to an answer that will be almost as full as your question is.

Comment: You're right that TTF does not support color glyphs HOWEVER makers have been embedding them in TTFs anyway. If you read my question I stated this several times...

Comment: Contrary to the quote you provided, [emoji-extrator](https://github.com/tmm1/emoji-extractor) was written to extract the color emoji from AppleColorEmoji.ttf. The color images are certainly in there. Custom extensions are used to retrieve them and that's what I was hoping to simulate here.

Comment: Sorry @naXa I think the downvotes are telling me to only accept real answers.

Comment: @im3r3k, great passion putting your rep out for an interesting question. Will be watching this space for a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I don't have an account, so let me start by apologizing for posting this as an answer instead of as a comment.

The picture you posted showing the Apple Color Emojis appear to come from a phone running an older version of Sense/Android, while the file you are referencing almost definitely comes from Sense 5-6/Android 4.3-4.4 If you look at the grayscale emojis you were able to extract from the file, you'll notice that they don't actually match up with the picture you provided. They do, however, match up with this: http://assets.hardwarezone.com/img/2013/10/HTC_One_Max_Emoticons_Keyboard_jpg.jpg

This leads me to conclude that it could be entirely possible that there are no conventional bitmaps stored in the TTF, rather there's some proprietary format that they use to assign colors to different parts of each emoji.

EDIT: Tried directly copying the file over to my phone to see what would happen (tried both replacing NotoColorFont.ttf as well as just directly copying and referencing it in fallback_fonts.xml, there doesn't seem to be any difference). Screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtOtS.jpg

As you can see, they show up without color, yet we already know that both the default Android emoji and Apple Color Emoji both show up fine on Android devices, meaning that HTC doesn't follow whatever standard that Android and iOS use.

Tested on a Galaxy SII (i9100) running CyanogenMod 11 Milestone 8.

Comment: Thanks, good info. Eventually will find out how they are encoded. Reverse engineering how the HTC device (apk?) reads the TTF and displays them may be an option.

Answer (score 1):

The emoji images in the `AndroidEmoji-htc.ttf` file are *probably* (since I don't have the font to test) stored in the same format as the standard Android emoji in Google's [CBLC](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/cblc.htm)+[CBDT](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/cbdt.htm) OpenType tables.

You can disassemble/reassemble the font using `ttx` from FontTools([pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/FontTools), [github](https://github.com/behdad/fonttools)) to confirm.

The direct answer to your question "What is the format?" is two options:

> **Uncompressed Color Bitmaps**
>
> The value ‘32’ of the bitDepth field of bitmapSizeTable struct defined in the CBLC table, to identify color bitmaps with 8-bit blue/green/red/alpha channels per pixel, encoded in that order for each pixel (referred to as BGRA from hereon). The color channels represent pre-multiplied color and are encode colors in the sRGB colorspace. For example, the color “full-green with half translucency” is encoded as \x00\x80\x00\x80, and not \x00\xFF\x00\x80.
>
> All imageFormat values defined in the EBDT / EBLC tables are valid for use with the CBDT / CBLC tables.
>
> **Compressed Color Bitmaps**
>
> Images for each individual glyph are stored as straight PNG data. Only the following chunks are allowed in such PNG data: IHDR, PLTE, tRNS, sRGB, IDAT, and IEND. If other chunks are present, the behavior is undefined. The image data shall be in the sRGB colorspace, regardless of color information that may be present in other chunks in the PNG data. The individual images must have the same size as expected by the table in the bitmap metrics.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, Emojis are stored in two different placfes - in .ttf - to display in text-only fields (for example, quick previews of message) and in images. Maybe you should dig into that way?

Comment: On OSX/ iOS devices they show color emoji in text fields. Apple once stored them in images but moved them to a ttf in iOS5. Sometimes images are stored on the device separately such as on Samsung devices currently but not the complete set. The complete sets of color emoji that I have found have always been in ttfs.

Comment: Here is a HTC user on [xda-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2588367) who could not find the images on the HTC device. Just like LG I think these emojis are solely in the TTF.

Comment: As I know, TTF could not store multi-color images... Or I'm wrong?

Comment: You can put color images in a TTF just like you could also put a sound clip. It is possible, but getting them out is a trick because it's not standard so no tools are available to do it. Google and Apple have been putting color images in TTFs to display emojis but they also write the tools to make sure they come out properly. So, you're right in that no TTF editing program that follows the TTF standard would be able to work with these.

Comment: Yes, you're right. There's an utility in ruby: https://github.com/tmm1/emoji-extractor

Maybe you can dig into it?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't looked at Android emoji but I managed to extract out the iOS emoji
by jacking a few tools to do it as nothing on the net seems to do it 100%.
Hex Editor is key its all I used...

iOS 5.0 used uint8 type RGBA data stored as tuples

iOS 5.1 changed to pngs and these are written contiguously

iOS 6 combined both the iOS 5.0 & 5.1 format. Set 1 & 2 were uint8 type data & Set 3 (ipad @ 96x96px) were optimised png format that Apple adopt e.g switching RGBA to BGRA...byte blitting apparently...

iOS 7 stayed the same as did iOS 8 to 8.2.

Hope that helps...